# How to inject PHP code with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, exploit

The following from a php webpage looks to me like some code which could be exploited.

```
# Maps a uri like questions/ask/index.php?anything=something to questions/ask/index.php
$path = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?"));
```

Can one of the following statements be exploited by a an attacker sending php syntax in the request uri? And if so, how do you avoid that?

**Variant 1:**

```
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&tag='.$tags);
```

**Variant 2:**

```
<p>...<?php echo $path; ?>... </p>
```

Comment: the request uri was use to load the page, if there was php in it the server would have used the raw php as an url- unusual i  would say

Comment: The **ONLY** time any PHP code which comes in via REQUEST_URI, or $_POST, etc... could ever be executed is if it gets placed into an executable context. e.g. `eval($_POST['runme'])`. Simply having some PHP code in a string means nothing - It's just text. But if it gets placed into an executable context, then it's dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echoing PHP code doesn't make it run.  For example, try:

```
<?php 
$path = "echo 'hello';";
echo $path; 
?>
```

`echo 'hello';` is not going to be run.

For this to be a real vulnerability the app would have to be using [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) or something similar.

The real issue with printing out user input directly is Javascript injection or Cross-site scripting injection, not PHP injection.

Comment: The eval() function is mentioned in two places here, but a much more common attack vector is a poorly-written controller allowing injections into require_once/require/import. These functions generally support remote URLs, not just local filenames.