# Cross-Site Scripting PHP Get URL issue

Tags: php, xss, facebook-opengraph

I have a Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) issue on one of my sites. Right now I am using the following code to get each page's URL:

```
$pageurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $pageurlencode = "http%3A%2F%2F".urlencode($pageurl);
  $pageurl = "http://".$pageurl;
```

But, when I place the $pageurl into my open graph url (og:url), there is the issue (because, people can inject code there).

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $pageurl; ?>" />
```

So, my question is, how do I modify my $pageurl so malicious code doesn't get added?

---

I searched on StackOverflow for similar issues, but couldn't find any that address this specific issue (there were plenty of XSS, but none that pointed to fixing a get URL call). So, if you do see a duplicate, let me know where you saw it. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of injection are you experiencing? Anything coming through `$_SERVER` variables should already be sanitized. [See this related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274615/how-to-inject-php-code-with-serverrequest-uri)

Comment: Someone ran a test on my site using the URL. They said that when they entered https://www.example.com/?"><svg/onload=confirm(1)> into the browser, then inspecting the code showed the og:url as <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/?"><svg/onload=confirm(1)" /> ... if that's true, they could place code to steal my cookies.

Comment: Odd though... when I enter the same url, I inspect the code and see http://www.example.com/?%22%3E%3Csvg/onload=confirm(1)%3E ... which is safe. Could you tell me how to explain to him that there is no issue?  And why he may be seeing the code differently?

Answer (score 1):

And use always htmlspecialchars() on output for dynamic values (user input) to HTML source values.

Comment: So, just add a line at the end of my code above and say....

$pageurl = htmlspecialchars($pageurl);

Is that correct?

Comment: This way: `<meta property="og:url" content="<?= htmlspecialchars($pageurl, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"); ?>" />`
If you use another charset then UTF-8 then set it instead of it.

Comment: Or you described it above, but just remember you changes the value of the variable if yo use it somewhere else, instead of the HTML output. htmlspecialchars() ist just for the connex swapping to(!) HTML.

Comment: ``htmlspecialchars()`` is far from a one-fits-all solution. You need to pair that with common logic, because even sanitized user input can be malicious, such is the ``javascript:`` URI scheme and a range of elements which should **NEVER** contain user input.

Answer (score 1):

Your last comment was correct.

Query strings -- and any special characters, for that matter, are always encoded. The only possible way you could ever have this sort of injection was 1) if `< > "` etc. were [valid URL characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7109208/2535504) or 2) even [valid filename characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename). Notice that both sets exclude any HTML characters. The only time you would ever have to worry about injection was if you were using `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables in PHP and directly outputting them -- since those are decoded into plain text. Then, you would use `htmlentities` to properly sanitize them. [See this broader discussion on text injection.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/75958/does-injecting-querystring-values-directly-into-html-pose-a-security-risk)

Since you're directly accessing a valid URL string (through `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`), you will never get a non-valid (to spec) URL.

The browser should automatically handle this encoding before sending it over to the server, and if not, the server should guard against any malformed URL. Either way, your script doesn't need to worry about handling that.

**EDIT**

It appears you can have characters such as `< >` in filenames on Mac/Linux, however those will never be properly loaded by a server since they do not follow URL guidelines.

**EDIT 2**

I just tested this on a Node.JS server and it appears that it does manage to serve up files with special characters. To be safe, always encode using `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` as suggested on this page, however, I can never imagine someone having a filename with special HTML characters -- that's basically XSSing yourself -- but it's a good thing to be aware of.

**EDIT 3**

Curiosity got the best of me, and I deployed a file named `"<test.php` to my NGINX server running on a Linux VM. Here's partial output of `print_r($_SERVER)`:

```
 [DOCUMENT_URI] => /"<test.php
 [REQUEST_URI] => /%22%3Ctest.php
 [SCRIPT_NAME] => /"<test.php
```

Notice `REQUEST_URI` is still being encoded, even though the server is properly resolving the path. So, you can ignore my last edit, assuming you stick with `REQUEST_URI`. To reiterate, files should never be named with special characters, so this wouldn't be an issue either way.